# Iterate list of Objects in Ibatis

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I have a list of object where I want to iterate and access a particular field in ibatis sql.

Ex.

```
public Class Student
{
String id;
String name;
}
```

I will pass as parameter a List of Student object(List(Student))
and do iteration accessing the id for each object bean. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you please share code where you buld array and initialize objects

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **foreach**-tag is what you are looking for. Example:

```
<select id="selectPostIn" resultType="domain.blog.Post">
  SELECT *
   FROM POST P
   WHERE ID in
   <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">
    #{item}
   </foreach>
</select>
```

See the [user guide](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ibatis/java/ibatis-3/trunk/doc/en/iBATIS-3-User-Guide.pdf) for more info, chapter "dynamic sql".

By the way, iBatis is no longer developed and is frozen, it is now called "MyBatis" and the whole developer team moved away from Apache to the  [new MyBatis home](http://www.mybatis.org).

Comment: thanks. I'll try to see if this exists in ibatis2 and maybe change to mybatis.

Answer (score 6):

A simple example.

```
<select id="selectFewStudents" resultMap="MyMap" parameterClass="list">
    select * from student_table where student_id in
    <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
       #[]#
    </iterate>
</select>
```

Refer [iBatis documentation](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html) for more info.

As Sylar pointed out, the java equivalent would be

```
<select id="selectFewStudents" resultType="MyMap">
  select * from student_table where student_id in
   <foreach item="currentRow" index="rowNum" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">
    #{currentRow}
  </foreach>
</select>
```

iBatis allows you to variables item and index which you can use inside the loop.

Comment: This is true for .NET iBatis, but false for Java iBatis. In Java, the foreach tag is used to iterate over collections.

Comment: I don't think the difference is .NET vs Java but ibatis2 vs ibatis3. I'm using ibatis2 in Java and using the iterate tag. also using the #[]# syntax and not the #{} syntax.

Comment: Regarding the first example you mentioned.. You print only one value which is object? I dont understand this example

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
<select id="StudentsQry" parameterClass="list">

select * from STUDENTS where 
( id, name ) in 
        <iterate open="(" close=")" conjunction="," >
                ( #[].id# , #[].name# )
        </iterate>

<select>
```

where `id` and `name` are fields of `Student` class and my `parameterClass` is `List<Student>`.

Worked for me.

The sql formed dynamically will look like:

```
select * from STUDENTS where ( id, name ) in ( (1,'a'), (2,'b') )
```

Comment: self explained, nice.

Comment: How do you specify a class containing '<' and '>' in the parameterClass attribute?