# Java : Iterating a Set in ibatis

Tags: java, set, iteration, ibatis

I have a Set attribute in the model object.

```
    class AA{

        Set x;
    }
```

But when I try to iterate the Set in the ibatis xml file , I get the following exception.

```
   The 'x' property of the AA class is not a List or Array.
```

This is the stuff that is present in the ibatis xml file.

```
    <iterate property="x" open="(" close=")" conjunction=","> 

            #x[]#

      </iterate>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this question: [Iterate list of Objects in Ibatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360070/iterate-list-of-objects-in-ibatis)

They're talking about a List rather than a Set, but it appears that ibatis only supports iteration over Lists and Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked, although iBatis 3 UserGuide says "(...)need to iterate over **collection**" and then you are specifying "**collection**" field in foreach tag, Set is not supported.

Few lines below there is a note that only arrays and lists are supported.