# Multi value wildcard search in ibatis

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

I have a search field that can take values separated by blank spaces for multi-value search. But now I want to make it a multi-value search using wildcards. For example, if I add 'away%' and 'ds%' separated by a blank space in the search field it should search for both wild card values in a given column. The query should be as :

```
SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE [column] LIKE ('away%') OR
[column] LIKE ('ds%');
```

How can I achieve this repetitive column reference based on the number of search values? P.S: search value can be of any number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate list of Objects in Ibatis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360070/iterate-list-of-objects-in-ibatis)

Comment: The examples in the link shows the use of IN operator but I can't use IN here because I have wild card in the search.

Comment: You don't have to use IN, you can adapt that example to generate multiple OR conditions

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do that:

Mapper Class:

```java
List<MyEntity> search(String terms);
```

Mapper XML:

```
<select id="search" resultMap="myEntityResultMap">
    SELECT * FROM `my_table`
    <if test="_parameter != null">
        <where>
            <foreach collection="_parameter.split('\\s+')" item="item" open="(" close=")" separator=" OR ">
                name LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', #{item}), '%')
            </foreach>
        </where>
    </if>
</select>
```

Notes:

- `<if>` Checks for a null parameter. In that case, no `WHERE` clause will be added.
- `<foreach>` Splits the parameter using the `\s+` regex and then iterates over the results adding each term in a separate `name LIKE` clause and joining them by `OR`.
- `CONCAT(CONCAT('%', #{item}), '%')` Is written in this way to be used with Oracle database (takes two parameters in Oracle). It can be different in other database systems. For example, `CONCAT('%', #{item}, '%')` can be used in MySQL.